# matrix multiplication, confusion

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Am I correct to say that this matrix $C$ cannot be found 
$$C\times\left(\begin{array}{cc}
9 & 1\\ 4 & 6\\ 3 & 4\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}9&1\\4 & 6\\ 3&4\end{array}\right)$$

because the columns does not match the rows?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Matrix_product_.28two_matrices.29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, C must be a 3x3 matrix.

Comment: how does that work? 3X3 x2X3 != 2X3

Comment: 3x3 X 3x2 = 3x2

Comment: Try $C=I_3$ and multiplying it out for yourself.  Not positive it's the only solution, but it should work.

Comment: Oops! :/ Should have read that better

Comment: @Fatz: **first** the number of rows, *then* the number of columns. Your two matrices, other than $C$, are both $3\times 2$.

Comment: Yup got it, thanks :)